# 2D-Fourier-Transformation - correct order labeling?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, fft

I use the 2D-FFT from NumPy to calculate the differential phase of a patterned image. So I have an image with 20x20 spots which shift within several images and I want to get the shift / differential phase.

Therefore I use the following:

```
picfft = np.fft.fft2(data* hanning_window)
picfft_shifted = np.fft.fftshift(picfft)
```

Now I want to crop the different parts of the higher 1st order harmonics. From the [documentation of NumPy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft2.html) I read that, before shifting, the zero frequency is in the low-order corner and the positive frequencies are in the first half of the dimensions. After the `fftshift` this leads to the fact that the zero frequency is in the center and the positive frequencies in the left bottom quarter.

[image: in white the cropped areas of specific order]

If I now crop the 1st order areas as in the image and transform it back I get a quite reliable differential phase. However the sign is changed. I know that my spots shift to the middle of the image, but in the (1,0) and (0,1) orders the signs indicate a shift to the outer area of the image.

Have I interchanged the directions of crop, so is my (1,0) order in reality the (-1,0) order and so on? Because with this the results would fit to reality. But then my understanding of the documentation is different.

Hopefully anyone here is familiar with 2D-FFT and phase information.

Answer (score 0):

You have a description of what you do, rather than a demonstration (it’s always better to show code), but I think I know what might be amiss.

From your description it seems that you are cropping each of the modes of the frequency domain, and inverse transforming them. The crop has the origin (zero frequency) in the middle. It is imperative that you apply `ifftshift` to these crops before the inverse transform, such that the origin be moved to the top-left corner. Otherwise the phase of the inverse transform will be wrong.